# Is there a way to utilize a JSON path to fill out a search field and return the search result back in a hyperlink?

Tags: json

I am setting up a Manychat chatbot and want to use a JSON path to query a search field to return the search results back to the chat is this possible?

The search page is a Team Dynamix Knowledgebase. I have tried to google sample scripts to work with but have failed to find any.

Comment: can you supply example json?

Comment: @al76 I'm trying to find a sample I have failed to find any so I'm coming to the conclusion that it may not be possible with Json.